# Dynamically change Express routes on CMS update

Tags: javascript, express, next.js, contentful

I have a project using NextJS, with Express for server side routing.

**lib/routes/getPages**

```
const routes = require('next-routes')();
const getEntries = require('../helpers/getEntries');

module.exports = async (app) => {
  const { items: [globalSetings] } = await getEntries({
    content_type: 'xxxxxxxx',
    include: 1,
    limit: 1,
  });

  routes
    .add('/', 'index')
    .add(`/${globalSettings.fields.blogSlug}/:slug`, 'blog');

  return routes.getRequestHandler(app);
};
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const getPages = require('./lib/routes/getPages');

const app = next();

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = express();
  const pageRoutes = await getPages(app);
  server.use(pageRoutes);
  server.listen(3000);
});
```

I get slugs for routes (such as the blog section) from my CMS API (which is Contentful in this case). I am wondering how I handle an admin changing a slug in the CMS when the app is already running?

Guessing I will need to restart the app for the new slug/route to work. In this case, will I need to use a webhook and listen for changes from the CMS then somehow restart the app programmatically? This could work but might add overhead. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround in order to do dynamic routes in express.  Here's what I'm using in my Typescript app:

```
  // https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2596
  let dynamicRouter: express.Router
  app.use(
    (req, res, next) => dynamicRouter(req, res, next),
  )

  function loadMyRoutes() {
    const newRouter = express.Router()
    const newMiddleware = // load my new middleware

    newRouter.use(newMiddleware)

    dynamicRouter = newRouter
  }
```

You can then call `loadMyRoutes()` in response to a Contentful webhook.

```
app.post(`/webhook`, () => {
  loadMyRoutes()
})
```